# Event is not triggered on button press in handsontable

Tags: javascript, angular, handsontable

This is my component class in angular 4

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'food-list',
    templateUrl: 'foodList.component.html'
    })

    export class FoodListComponent implements OnInit {

     searchFoodForm: FormGroup;
     Food_foodName_eq: FormControl;
     Food_rating_eq: FormControl;
     Food_restaurants_restName_eq: FormControl;
     columns: object[] = [
      {data: 'id', title: 'Id'},
      {data: '11', title: 'rating'},
      {data: 'description', title: 'Description'},
      {data: 'foodName', title: 'Food Name', width: 200},
      {data: '<button (click)= 'editFood(1)'> Edit <button>', title: 'edit', 
      renderer: 'html'},
     ];
     instance: string = "hotInstance";
     data = [];

     constructor(private foodService: FoodService, private fb: FormBuilder,private _hotRegisterer: HotRegisterer) {
     this.createSearchForm();
    }

    createSearchForm() {
    this.searchFoodForm = this.fb.group({
      Food_foodName_eq: '',
      Food_rating_gt: '',
      Food_restaurants_restName_eq:''
     });
    }

    searchFood() {
     let searchParam = { "params": JSON.stringify(this.searchFoodForm.value) };
     this.fetchData(searchParam);
    }

    fetchData(searchParam){
     if(searchParam == "" || searchParam == undefined){
      searchParam = {"params" : searchParam};
     }
     this.foodService.getAll(searchParam).subscribe(suc => {
      let dataSchema = suc ;
      this.data = dataSchema["data"];
      this.columns = dataSchema["schema"];
     },
     err => {
      console.log("Something is wrong");
     })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
     let searchParam = "";
     this.fetchData(searchParam);

    }

    editFood(id:any){
     alert("uuuu");
    }

    }
```

and this is my component.html

```
   <hot-table
   height="250"
   [columns]="columns"
   [data]="data">
   </hot-table>
```

data is appearing in the handson table.I have a edit button in table.I want to call 'editFood(id:any)' function when edit button is pressed but it is not triggering.I rendered the cell as html.how can i bind this event with handsontable? No error is shown in the console.If i use alert function instead editFood function then it is triggered

Should i need to use a custom renderer for button ?

Comment: You can't do this, this is because Angular needs to compile the html in order to capture your bindings

Comment: hi @Milad, so if i put a edit button in handsontable ,it will not trigger any function?? how can it be logical??

Comment: as I said, this code needs to be compiled an injected into DOM via Angular, but you're using another library to do that for ya and expecting angular to understand it ! that can't be done, u can't use (click), try normal javascript events lile onclick="yourGlobalFunction()"

Comment: thanks @milad.i created a custom renderer in angular 5 HandsonsonTable wrapper but i can not find a way to register it.There is no "registerRenderer" method .So an error is shown in console like "No registered renderer found under "coverRenderer" name" .Can you explain please.Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the `afterOnCellMouseDown()` hook. When constructing the button in your table, give it a `class`, but do not include the `(click)` event.

```js
{data: '<button class="my-btn"> Edit </button>', title: 'edit', renderer: 'html'}
```

In your HTML:

```html
<hot-table hotId="myTable"
           height="250"
           [columns]="columns"
           [data]="data"
           (afterOnCellMouseDown)="myFunc($event)">
</hot-table>
```

Then in your component

```js
public myFunc(event) {
    if (event[0].realTarget.className.indexof('my-btn') > 0) {
        row = event[1].row
        const hotInst = this._hotRegisterer.getInstance('myTable')
        const id = hotInst.getDataAtRowProp(row, 'id')
        this.editFood(id)
    }
}
```

For a more complete example see [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/heqijexeci/1/edit?html,js,output)